# combining datetime.datetime with datetime.time - TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I am currently attempting to iterate through some data contained in an SQL request cursor, alter the type of some of the data into "datetime.time" and then combine that with another variable into a new variable named "datetime_db".

I have two variables named "date" and "nextDay" which have been previously defined earlier in my code. The previously mentioned "datetime.time" will be combined with either "date" or "nextDay" depending on certain conditions.

My code is as follows:

```
for (date_db,time_db,price) in cursor:
    time_db = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_db,"%H:%M:%S").time()
    price = float(price)

    if (date_db == date):
        datetime_db = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(date), datetime.time(time_db))

    else:
        datetime_db = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(nextDay), datetime.time(time_db))
```

This throws up the following error:

```
File "C:/Users/Stuart/PycharmProjects/untitled/Apache - Copy.py", line 82, in <module>
datetime_db = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(date), datetime.time(time_db))
TypeError: an integer is required
```

When I print out the "type()" for the 3 variables involved I get the following:

```
time_db = <type 'datetime.time'> date = <type 'datetime.datetime'> nextDay = <type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Is there any obvious reason why this is not working? I have tried changing the type of "date" and "nextDay" to a "datetime.date" but that makes no difference.

Could someone suggest how I may combine these two variables successfully?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot convert a `datetime` to `date` by the constructor:

```
>>> datetime.date(datetime.datetime.now())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Same goes for `datetime.time` constructor; it would not accept another `time` object as a parameter.

Now, you need to have a `date` and a `time` to use the `datetime.combine`; `time_db` is an instance of class `time` already, but your `date` (unfortunate name there for this explanation) is of type `datetime`. Well, that `date` part of `date` can be extracted with `datetime.date` method:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 20, 22, 21, 22, 806109)
>>> dt.date()
datetime.date(2015, 2, 20)
```

thus you can do:

```
datetime.datetime.combine(date.date(), time_db)
```

Comment: Thanks - I have now changed the "type()" of "date" and "nextDay" to "datetime.date" just above the "if statement" but I am still getting the same error - although strangely now it is referencing "datetime_db = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(nextDay), datetime.time(time_db))" as the erroneous line and seems to be getting past the prevoously flagged line. Is there any reason it would seem to work for one of the lines but not the other?

Comment: Or perhaps a better comment from me would be, "would you be able to guide me as to the correct way to go about achieving my aim of combining the two elements"

Comment: How about the last block of code that I gave to you (provided that `date` is still a `datetime`)

Comment: Yes - sorry I am being rather slow - I hadn't read it properly. That did indeed work. Much appreciated, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation for `combine`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine):

```
datetime_db = datetime.datetime.combine(date.date(), time_db.timetz())
```

This assumes that both `date` and `time_db` are `datetime` objects, which they appear to be.

Comment: Thanks Mark - I tried that but get the following message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Stuart/PycharmProjects/untitled/Apache - Copy.py", line 83, in <module>
    datetime_db = datetime.datetime.combine(date.date(), time_db.timetz())
AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'timetz'

Comment: Awesome! I just removed the ".timetz()" from the end and it works now - very much appreciated - thanks!!

Comment: Isn't that pretty much exactly what Antti recommended before?

Comment: Yes it is....I hadn't read the reply closely enough. I have now accepted the answer. Thanks all.